# Symfony 2.1 FOSFacebookBundle infinite loop after login

Tags: loops, symfony, authentication, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I've a little problem with the FOSFacebookBundle integration to my website. When I click on the "Connexion" button, user is redirected to /facebook/login_check, and some random token are added to the url (state and code). But a new value is given to these tokens every second, and the page is still blank.

Here is my code:

[config.yml]

```
security:
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
    my_fos_facebook_provider:
        id: my.facebook.user
firewalls:
    public:
        pattern:   ^/facebook
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=[MY_APP_ID]"
            server_url: "http://localhost/[MY_APP]/app_dev/"
            login_path: /facebook/login
            check_path: /facebook/login_check
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            default_target_path: /
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
    main:
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            provider:  fos_userbundle
```

[routing.yml]

```
_security_check:
    pattern:  /facebook/login_check
_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
```

[layout.html.twig]

```
<script>
      function goLogIn(){
          window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_check') }}";
      }

      function onFbInit() {
          if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
              FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                  if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
                      setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
                  } else {
                      window.location.href = "{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}";
                  }
              });
          }
      }
</script>
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I use Symfony 2.1 and FOSUserBundle.